# Add additional LED to illuminated momentary power switch

Tags: power-supply, led, parallel, series

I am using a microcontroller-based 5V input, 5V ouput power-switch (PetrockBlock) for my Raspberry Pi project. It provides pins for a power switch and for a power status LED. I am using a momentary illuminated switch and all is well. The nice thing about this setup is that the LED pulses during boot-up and shutdown.

This is described by the manufacturer as a 5V status LED, as shown below.

### **Pin Out for Status LED**

The current power state of the Raspberry Pi can be indicated with a 5V status LED that can be attached to the two pins that are provided by the PowerBlock. These states can be “off”, “booting”, “on”, and “shutdown”. The different state are indicated with easy-to-distinguish static and pulsing patterns.

### Mini Illuminated Momentary Power Button

The button is described as:

Voltage rating for tactile switch: 12V

Current rating for tactile switch: 50mA

Current rating for LED: ~10mA

This works nicely. If anything it is a little bright. I have not added a resistor into the circuit, I presume this is provided on the PetrockBlock.

### My question:

I want to add a second LED (white) that shares the behaviour of the button LED so as to add illumination behind a small logo.
Can I just wire a white LED in series? I think that would mean the voltage would be shared and they would be dimmer? Would I need to add a resistor? Or should I wire them in parallel? Again, would I need a resistor.

Without a bit of guidance I am reluctant to experiment with the PetrockBlock (@ £25).

Any help appreciated.

[image: Image of 8-pin chip]

I found a data sheet for the switch. The relevant bit is below:[image: part of data sheet]

Comment: There's no instruction other than you can connect a LED and 5V being mentioned. It is unknown what kind of output it has to drive the LED unless you have the schematics. This is just "how to use a product" question due to lack of manufacturer info. It is also unknown if the pushbutton indicator LED has a resistor or not. Having said that, just put resistors and drive the two LEDs in parallel, because you can't drive them in series. You need the resistors for many reasons, one being you can't e.g. parallel a red and white LED as only the red would turn on.

Comment: Datasheet link to your switch thingy is where?

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a real datasheet and the photo is too blurry to make out the chip, but it looks like it's doing current limiting for the status LED internally.  Can you give us a close up photo of the 8-pin chip or the marking on its top?  Might be easiest to just use a voltage follower to drive the LED especially if it's being dimmed.

Comment: I think it fair to say I know how to use the product as intended. I just followed the instructions and it works. I am hoping to do something it is not specifically designed to do, but lack the understanding of electronics to know how to do it safely. I will try to get a picture of the chip. Thanks for the comments so far.

Comment: Image of 8-pin chip added.

Comment: What color is the switch LED?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Sorry, I knew that colour is a thing. It is a blue LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the switch LED is a blue LED and your desired LED is a white one, they will both have similar voltage drop (white LEDs use blue dies plus phosphor).

Since the board supplies about 10mA according to the datasheet, we can assume there's a resistor of about 200-300Ω on the board, assuming a 5V supply. To make the two currents relatively equal we should put some resistance in series with each, perhaps 150Ω. Each LED will end up with 2-5 mA (the total will be a bit less than the original current because we need to add voltage drops in order to roughly equalize the two currents).

Here is an example simulation, I've made the LEDs similar but with a somewhat different forward voltage. D1 drops 2.6V at 5.1mA and D2 drops 2.8V at 2.4mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFgrfN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can experiment with other resistor values (unbalanced or not) from zero to infinity, you can't hurt anything (directly) by playing around. If one LED is unacceptably dim compared to the other try making the series resistor for that one lower in resistance.

Comment: Apparently I'm not supposed to post a comment to say thank you. So instead... I tried out your solution on a breadboard. I had to use the closest values I could find for the resistors and only had a red led switch and a white led to play with. Anyway, it works. Both leds are dim, but there was no smoke and I have the confidence to experiment with the values.

Comment: @clarke-baxter Feedback decribing how things worked out is always welcome, IMO. The red LED will hog the current so it's not really indicative (so to speak) of performance with blue/white LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the extra LED circuit in parallel with the other and add an extra resistor. The value of the resistor (R1) depends on the voltage supply (V1) available and the forward voltage of the LED (Vf LED). The more current (I LED) allowed to flow the brighter the LED. You will need to follow the specifications of the LED you select to find Vf and the allowable LED current (I LED). Note that a white LED often requires a higher voltage then a single color LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy57Ah.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>